# Main is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, variables, types, foreach

Basically, I attempted to use this code found from StackOverflow which was associated with some colision detection I wanted between my pictureBoxes. However, I encounter an error stating that the Form name is a type but is used like a variable. The code is here:

```
foreach (Control PictureBox in Main)
{
    if (Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds))
    {

    }
}
```

In the foreach loop. It is underlining the word Main, stating these exact words:

```
'Namespace.Main' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Comment: How have you created `Main` in your program?

Comment: Basically, main is the form. Sorry for not stating this, it's the form name.

Comment: is thie C#? please tag it

Comment: Sorry about that, was told not to do that before and my post was edited I believe. Tagged now.

Comment: Yes, the error tells you should put a variable in the foeach loop. Are you gonna test every PictureBox with your Player.Bounds? Or maybe you could show us the original link of the so post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Main` is a *class*. You can't iterate over a class, you have to iterate over an object. Specifically (in this case), you have to iterate over a collection of `Control` objects. I think maybe you wanted:

```
foreach (Control pictureBox in Controls)
```

Here, I'm iterating over the `Controls` property of the current object. This is assuming you are doing this from inside the instance of `Main`. Otherwise, you will need a reference to the `Form` object and use:

```
foreach (Control pictureBox in myFormObject.Controls)
```

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls.get'

Comment: Sorry - have just updated my answer. I'm assuming you're doing this from *within* the form.